# Reimplimenting insertRows in a table's DataModel

Tags: qt4, pyqt4, qtableview

I'm trying to implement a `insertRow` function (very similar to the overridable`insertRows`).
This is what I've done:

```
def insertRow(self, row_data, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
    self.beginInsertRows(parent, self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
    self.arraydata.append(row_data)
    self.endInsertRows()
```

This doesn't show anything on the `QTableView` itself (even though it extends the left scroller).

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the table was empty at first, and because of that, the `columnCount` was also zero. I needed to call `beginInsertColumns` and `endInsertColumns` as well.